# custom script install for website

Tags: web-services

I need help with a script called : VIAVI NEWS, it's supposed to have the step by step instructions but I've been having difficulties and the help support is not helping. Can anyone help me with this? It's really important to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved !
Just had to update the php version, thanks anyway